# Recently unparented object doesn't behave independently blender python

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, parent

I'm trying to simulate stage seperation of a rocket and it requires unparenting the object. It was first parented so it could follow the same route as another stage, but when it was uparented, the object refused to behave independently. File [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQJ9umHiMsN94IYlZdOv_VrHTnGqIFh_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Most likely your object still has a keyframed transform. It's better if you provide enough information in the body of your question rather than having users download random files. Cheers :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I don't see any keyframing on my object other than the parent object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your simulation is going to run a very long time. In fact, your python code mentions frame numbers beyond where you have the end set.  Perhaps you could point out the approximate frame range where the problem is easily visible?

Comment: To clarify, the issue is happening at frame 250, as you can see in line 118 and beyond, Stage 1 is suppose to "unparent" and separate. And I'm aware the frames are off, I miscalculated the amount of frames required, Thanks in advance.